# How do I properly use evil-set-jump? Doesn't seem to work if I pass a point position

Tags: evil

I have my own function that essentially wraps `outline-up-heading` in Org-mode. It doesn't seem to take into account Evil's jump points, so Evil's `C-o` takes me to elsewhere. I'm trying to add support for Evil's jump points, but with a dubitable outcome. Evil doesn't have too much in terms of documentation for internal features and use of its functions, so idk if I'm approaching it wrong or it's a bug in Evil.

If I try to be smart and don't always create the jump point, for the case of when the current outline level is already the top—then `C-o` still doesn't work properly, and takes me e.g. to the previously edited file:

```el
(defun my-outline-up-heading (arg &optional invisible-ok)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((original-point (point))
        (original-line-number (line-number-at-pos)))
    (outline-up-heading arg invisible-ok)
    (when (not (equal original-line-number (line-number-at-pos)))
      (evil-set-jump original-point))))
```

However, if I just set the jump point regardless of conditions, then `C-o` works just fine:

```el
(defun my-outline-up-heading (arg &optional invisible-ok)
  (interactive "p")
  (evil-set-jump)
  (outline-up-heading arg invisible-ok))
```

In the first variant, the condition triggers, but it looks like `evil-set-jump` with the argument does nothing. Is there a way to make it work?